# Ruby on Rails: How can i get the username from users table with Post.paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In index action of PostController

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

posts table

```
                                   Table "public.posts"
   Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers                      
-------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass)
 title       | character varying(100) | not null
 content     | character varying(500) | not null
 created_at  | date                   | 
 updated_at  | date                   | 
 tags        | character varying(55)  | not null default '50'::character varying
 category_id | integer                | not null default 1
 user_id     | integer                | 
Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

users table

```
                                           Table "public.users"
         Column         |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 email                  | character varying(255)      | not null default ''::character varying
 encrypted_password     | character varying(128)      | not null default ''::character varying
 reset_password_token   | character varying(255)      | 
 reset_password_sent_at | timestamp without time zone | 
 remember_created_at    | timestamp without time zone | 
 sign_in_count          | integer                     | default 0
 current_sign_in_at     | timestamp without time zone | 
 last_sign_in_at        | timestamp without time zone | 
 current_sign_in_ip     | character varying(255)      | 
 last_sign_in_ip        | character varying(255)      | 
 confirmation_token     | character varying(255)      | 
 confirmed_at           | timestamp without time zone | 
 confirmation_sent_at   | timestamp without time zone | 
 username               | character varying(255)      | not null
 is_admin               | boolean                     | default false
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone | 
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_users_on_confirmation_token" UNIQUE, btree (confirmation_token)
    "index_users_on_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
    "index_users_on_reset_password_token" UNIQUE, btree (reset_password_token)
    "index_users_on_username" UNIQUE, btree (username)
```

I need to get username from users table(need joining), not the user_id from posts table. I have used pagination in index.html.erb

Getting the username how can i display the username of a post in index.html.erb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just simple include should do the trick:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC', :include => :user)
```

and then in the view:

```
post.user.username
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But is there any other way to do the same thing? And how does this include work? If i use `Post.find` then how can i get the username ?

Comment: include joins the tables, so all the users data is loaded together with the posts with a single query.
With Post.find - just the same thing: `Post.find(:order => 'created_at', :include => :user)`

Comment: @alony :come join my chat here...pls